# Subtracting days from a date using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to subtract X days from a date retrieved from MySQL.
X is a variable that can be any integer.

I tried:

```
$days = trim(explode("days",explode("Order will be late by",$resPO['EXCEPTION_MSG'])[1])[0]); // returning a number 1, 2, 3, etc
$date = $resPO['DUE_DESIRED_RECV_DATE']; //date from database 
$reqdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$days days", strtotime($date)));
```

Resulting: 04/30/2021

No matter what the date is inserted into the formula. HOWEVER, when I manually change the formula to a constant, it does calculate properly.

Example:

```
$reqdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-3 days", strtotime($date)));
```

EDIT:
The $days is working fine when I use a manual date like "2021-04-30". So, looks like the problem is the date I am getting from MySQL.
It is set as DATE and is printing properly.

EDIT 2:

```
// FORMATTING DATE
$days = $resPO['ORDER_PROJ_LATE_BY'];
//$days = 3; 
$date = $resPO['DUE_DESIRED_RECV_DATE']; //date from database
                                            
$new_date = explode("-",$date);
$var_new_date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$new_date[1],$new_date[2] - $days,$new_date[0]));

$newdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$days days", strtotime($var_new_date)));
```

EDIT 3:
I found a workaround by multiplying the DAYS (int) from MySQL by 3 and then dividing the results by 3.1 (closer as possible to 3).

```
// FORMATTING DATE
$days = $resPO['ORDER_PROJ_LATE_BY'];
$days = ($days * 3)/3.1;
```

Any help?

Comment: Did you try printing out the $date?

Comment: Yes @franziga. There are the results I got:
`2020-03-16
2020-12-31
2021-03-17
2021-04-01
2021-04-01
2021-04-05
2021-04-19
2021-04-19
2021-04-19
2021-04-22
2021-04-22
2021-04-22
2021-04-25
2021-04-26
2021-04-26
2021-04-27
2021-04-28
2021-04-28
2021-04-28
2021-04-28
2021-04-28
2021-04-29
2021-04-29
2021-04-29
2021-04-29
2021-04-29
2021-04-29
2021-04-29`

Comment: But why did you get "04/30/2021" instead of "2021-04-30"?

Comment: Sorry, just a formatting function. I took the formatting function off and it shows "2021-04-30".

Comment: Then it should be the problem of `$resPO['EXCEPTION_MSG']` (i.e. `$days`)

Comment: That's what I figured. I changed the script to get an INTEGER from MySQL and stored at "$days = $resPO['ORDER_PROJ_LATE_BY'];". Still not working.

Comment: Perhaps you should print `"-$days days"` out to see

Comment: `-3 days -3 days -3 days -3 days -3 days -3 days -3 days -4 days -4 days -4 days -5 days -5 days -5 days -5 days -5 days -6 days -6 days -6 days -7 days -7 days -7 days -7 days -7 days -7 days -7 days -10 days -10 days -10 days -10 days -10 days -10 days -10 days -10 days -10 days -10 days`

Comment: I can't see any problems. Perhaps you write a console program with minimum code. Perhaps the problem is from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

your code is alright, can it be that the date read from MySQL - in $resPO['DUE_DESIRED_RECV_DATE'] - has an unconventional formatting? strtotime expects them to be formatted in one of the [recognized formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

```
$days = 3;
$date = '2021-05-01';
$reqdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$days days", strtotime($date)));
echo "$reqdate\n";
```

returns

```
2021-04-28
```

Comment: Yes, this is actually working. The problem is the date I'm getting from MySQL. However, when I print the date from MySQL i literally get it right (the date itself) but can't get it to work when I use the date in the formula to subtract the $days.

Comment: can you show result of echo this: $resPO['DUE_DESIRED_RECV_DATE']."\n";

Comment: Sure, there are the results I got:
`2020-03-16
2020-12-31
2021-03-17
2021-04-01
2021-04-01
2021-04-05
2021-04-19
2021-04-19
2021-04-19
2021-04-22
2021-04-22
2021-04-22
2021-04-25
2021-04-26
2021-04-26
2021-04-27
2021-04-28
2021-04-28
2021-04-28
2021-04-28
2021-04-28
2021-04-29
2021-04-29
2021-04-29
2021-04-29
2021-04-29
2021-04-29
2021-04-29`

Comment: for clarity - does one mysql row contain multiple dates? if not - it should work just fine with code attached.

Comment: Thanks for asking. It is not possible for one row containing multiple dates.